# How to properly measure the power being delivered to a BLDC?

Tags: power, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

There's a battery connected to an ESC, connected to the Motor, coupled to a Dyno.

How can I measure the electrical power going into the BLDC?

As far as I'm concerned a simple measurement of line voltage and line current (the BLDC is wye-wound) cannot accurately output the necessary data for power calculation since many harmonics need to be taken into account and power is more appropriately calculated by multiplying 3*(phase voltage*phase current). The problem is only the three-phases are available and the neutral point is connected inside the stator out of reach.

I know I could use the power output from the battery which is easily measured with 2 DMMs and subtract from the mechanical power but I would not be able to account ESC losses.

Thus, what would be the most appropriate way to measure the electric power going into the motor?
Would digital multimeters suffice or a power analyser would be the best option?